# ui-screen-shooter not running

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation

I am using ui-screen-shooter to try to take localized screen shots, but i am having issues running ./ui-screen-shooter.   I've followed all the instructions and think i have all the script files.  but i get the following error when i run ./ui-screen-shooter:

```
./ui-screen-shooter.sh ~/Desktop/screenshots
/Users/andyphillips404/Documents/Projects/DoggeryApps/Photo Finish/config-screenshots.sh: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I am not sure what is wrong.   Here is a copy of my config-screenshots.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is an example configuration file to be used with ui-screen-shooter
# It is designed to work with the Hello World International application
# Please copy to config-screenshots.sh and edit for your needs


# LOCALE
# ======
# Set the locales here in which your screenshots should be made.
# Use format like en-US zh-Hans for filenames compatible with iTMSTransporter
# Note: to get the locale names for your existing app:
#  - Download .itmsp file with iTMSTransporter
#  - Run `grep locale ~/Desktop/*.itmsp/metadata.xml  | grep name | sort -u`

export languages="en-US da de es fr it ja nl pt ru zh-Hans zh-Hant”


# SIMULATORS
# ==========
# The simulators we want to run the script against, declared as a Bash array.
# Run `instruments -s devices` to get a list of all the possible string values.

declare -xa simulators=(
"iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)",
"iPhone 6 Plus (8.1 Simulator)",
"iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator)",
"iPhone 4s (8.1 Simulator)"
)
```

Anyone have any idea, guessing the issue is with the declare statement from the error code but can't figure out why....

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of ui-screen-shooter?

Comment: Yes, i emailed him as well.   Although i just did email him, i am on a tight deadline and hoped to get the answer here quicker if anyone has a clue...

Comment: Try escaping the parentheses of your simulator names. Unless I've miscounted, line 24 (the line your script is complaining about) is `"iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)",`. Try `"iPhone 6 \(8.1 Simulator\)",`. I really don't think it'll work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot, and sorry for wasting everyone's time.  I need to stop using the basic text editor on a mac.   It changes the " to ” as you can see from the posting above.   The last character in the export line above the line in issue is what was causing all the problems....

changed it back to a " and we are good...   not the first time that has burned me... sorry guys....